# Always getting "unable to geocode" in Nominatim?

Tags: reverse-geocoding, nominatim

I've installed Nominatim and everything seems to work fine, but whenever I try to use the reverse geocoding API, all I get is "unable to geocode". Strangely, the search function works well and returns lots of information for a location.

Example: The search for the coordinates 40.724362, -74.002339 correctly returns an address in NYC when entered in the search field:

[image: Search function of Nominatim working fine]

But when I run

```
http://localhost/reverse.php?format=json&lat=40.724362&lon=-74.002339&zoom=18&addressdetails=1
```

The response is:

```
{"error":"Unable to geocode"}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827902/get-a-query-from-url-in-php

Comment: Yes I've seen that. But it's a different problem than mine. I'm sure my request is correct, because if I exchange "localhost" with "nominatim.openstreetmaps.org" it works fine. I still tried this solution but I still get "unable to geocode".

Comment: What does your reverse.php file look like?

Comment: I haven't modified it, it looks exactly like the one [on GitHub](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim/blob/master/website/reverse.php).

Comment: What is the response when you call with debug = 1 as a parameter?

Comment: what ended up resolving this issue?